# Filter nsarray by comparing specific element

Tags: objective-c, filter, nsmutablearray

i am on Objective-C, Xcode 8.3, OSX not iOS.

I have an NSMutableArrays like this

```
NSMutableArray* A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one string", @"another string", @"third string", nil];
NSMutableArray* B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one string", @"second string", nil];
NSMutableArray* C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one string", @"second string", @"third string", nil];
```

All arrays are nested inside another array

```
NSMutableArray allArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: A,B,C,nil];
```

I want to filter through allArrays so that if the LAST element (no matter how many items are in) isEqual to "third string", then all elements of THAT array get removed except the FIRST

Result for above example should be:

```
@[
@[@"one string"], // A
@[@"one string", @"second string"], // B
@[@"one string"]  // C
]
```

I already got a working solution with iteration and comparing but there must be something more effective!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: if you have solution then paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter version of Maheshs answer:

```
// enumerate the outer array
[allArrays enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSMutableArray *innerArray, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    // test last object
    if ([innerArray.lastObject isEqualToString:@"third string"]) {
        // remove objects after the first object
        [innerArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(1, innerArray.count - 1)];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one string", @"another string", @"third string", nil];
NSMutableArray* B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one string", @"second string", nil];
NSMutableArray* C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one string", @"second string", @"third string", nil];


NSMutableArray *allArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: A,B,C,nil];


for (NSMutableArray *innerArray in allArrays)
{
    //check that inner is not empty
    if (innerArray.count > 0)
    {
        //Compare the last object
        if ([[innerArray lastObject] isEqualToString:@"third string"])
        {
            //copy first string
            NSString *firstString = [innerArray firstObject];

            //remove all items from array
            [innerArray removeAllObjects];

            //Now insert copied string into empty array
            [innerArray addObject:firstString];
         }

    }

}

NSLog(@"%@",allArrays);
```